# Exchange Server/CCR/Primary To Secondry Moved Failed

Tags: exchange-2007, windows-cluster

Operation System : Windows Server 2003 Ent 64bit

Exchange Server Version : Exchange Server 2007 SP3

We had TWO Mail Boxes Server (PHYSICAL MACHINE) with CCR, Few Days back one of our Secondary Mail Box Server Machine Gone Faulty and we ready another Mailbox Server but this time on HYPER V VM , Machine works fine as Secondary.

But

When we try to move group for new machine as a "Primary Mail Box" server it was stuck on MS Cluster End and unable to transfer and got this error

The crypto checkpoint for cluster resource 'Exchange Information Store Instance (khi-cms-01)' could not be restored to the container name 'C44FBC30-1445-11d3-8CAA-00104B9C5823'. The resource may not function correctly.

We have Identified that this error causes due to Forefront installation at Primary Server so we removed Forefront but Issue Remains Same but errors are changed this time.

Here are Error Events on Primary Mail Box Server:

Event Id : 4

"The kerberos client received a KRB_AP_ERR_MODIFIED error from the server host/khi-mbx-01.dib.ae.  The target name used was khi-cms-01. This indicates that the password used to encrypt the kerberos service ticket is different than that on the target server. Commonly, this is due to identically named  machine accounts in the target realm (DIB.AE), and the client realm.   Please contact your system administrator."

Event id :1069

Cluster resource 'Exchange Information Store Instance (khi-cms-01)' in Resource Group 'khi-cms-01' failed.

Event id : 7034

The Microsoft Exchange Information Store service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 8 time(s).

Event id : 1009

Cluster service could not join an existing server cluster and could not form a new server cluster. Cluster service has terminated.

Event id 40960

The Security System detected an authentication error for the server cifs/KHI-AD-02.DIB.AE.  The failure code from authentication protocol Kerberos was "The time at the Primary Domain Controller is different than the time at the Backup Domain Controller or member server by too large an amount.
 (0xc0000133)".

Here are Events on Secondry Mail Box Server :

Event id :7034

The Microsoft Exchange Information Store service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 8 time(s).

Event id : 1069

Cluster resource 'Exchange Information Store Instance (khi-cms-01)' in Resource Group 'khi-cms-01' failed.

Event id : 4

The kerberos client received a KRB_AP_ERR_MODIFIED error from the server host/khi-mbx-01.dib.ae.  The target name used was khi-cms-01. This indicates that the password used to encrypt the kerberos service ticket is different than that on the target server. Commonly, this is due to identically named  machine accounts in the target realm (DIB.AE), and the client realm.   Please contact your system administrator.

Event id : 29

The time provider NtpClient is configured to acquire time from one or more time sources, however none of the sources are currently accessible.  No attempt to contact a source will be made for 1 minutes. NtpClient has no source of accurate time.

Pls Help ............................

Answer (score 0):

Kindly ensure the Exchange Rollups and OS Updates on both of the Mailbox Servers are the same

and let me know ...

since this issue may be because of the different patch level of mailbox servers